# Populate field value dynamically from master object

Tags: custom-object

Have DOB date field in master object and want the DDMM format data out of the value from that field to be populate in child object number field. How can i do that. Both fields have different datatypes.

Comment: @Himanshu was being nice; normally on SFSE we request the poster to demonstrate in their question what they have tried and why it is not working.

Comment: Sure, will take care :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use process builder to update child object. I am assuming that you have two different child object fields called Month(Number) and Date (Number)

1. Use **MONTH(date)** which returns the month, a number between 1 (January) and 12 (December)
2. Use **Day(date)** which returns the day of the month, a number between 1 and 31

Comment: Thanks, but i have only one child field which has to take value as DDMM from DOB. I tried to use DAY concatenate MONTH but it throws an error.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: I used it like DAY(Customer__r.DOB__c)  &   MONTH( Customer__r.DOB__c ) and got an error "Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '&'. Expected Text, received Number"

Comment: it is DAY(Customer__r.DOB__c) + MONTH( Customer__r.DOB__c )

Comment: If your DDMM field is a text type field, you need to use the TEXT() function on your values before concatenating them. This would look like... TEXT(DAY(Customer__r.DOB__c)) & TEXT(MONTH( Customer__r.DOB__c )). Note that if you need to enforce two digits for each, you will have to add an IF() to add in the extra '0' before the values.